What is the `Evaluate script` that is executed before `Parse HTML`?
I measured the performance of the following empty HTML with the Performance panel of Chrome DevTools.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

The result of the performance measurement was as follows. I thought it started with Parse HTML, but I found Evaluate script and Event: visibilitychange before Parse HTML. What are these processes doing?

